# Debugging direct Cython code on Windows

Tags: debugging, cython

I am wondering if it is possible to directly debug Cython code on Windows, without having to debug in the intermediate C file?  Currently, when I build my Cython extension module, I obtain a .PDB file (Visual Studio debugging symbols) and the "cython_debug" folder (Cygdb symbols).  However, it seems that I cannot make use of Cygdb (and thus the "cython_debug" folder) because GDB is not able to find any debugging symbols in Python, which I believe is, in turn, because Python is built with the Visual Studio (MSVC) toolset on Windows.  Currently, the only way that I have been able to debug the Cython extension is with the intermediate C code in the Visual Studio Debugger, which is an enormous amount of code and requires understanding the translation from Cython to C.  What would I need to do in order to debug at the layer of the Cython code itself?  Would this require building Python itself -- and all of the 3rd-party Python libraries that I'm using -- with the GNU GCC toolset instead, in a way that is not compatible with the publicly-released versions of Python?  Or is there any way to get the necessary GDB symbols in the MSVC build?

Was Cygdb -- and the system of using the "cython_debug" folder -- only designed for use in Linux and not Windows?

Comment: Any news on this? I'd like to figure this out as well with VS Code.